# Node JS : How to retrive data from frontend after a res.json(data) in backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

my backend send a res.staus(200).json({*somedata*)} to my front, but i can't retrieve the data in the frontend.

My backend :

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  //===== Check if user exists in DB ======
  const { user_email, user_password: clearPassword } = req.body;
  let sql = `SELECT user_password, user_id FROM users WHERE user_email=?`;
  db.query(sql, [user_email], async (err, results) => {
    console.log(results);
    console.log(req.body);
    if (err) {
      return res.status(404).json({ err });
    }

    // ===== Verify password with hash in DB ======
    const { user_password: hashedPassword, user_id } = results[0];
    try {
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(clearPassword, hashedPassword);
      if (match) {
        console.log("match ... user_id : ", user_id);

        // If match, generate JWT token
        res.status(200).json({
          test: 'iyu',
          user_id: user_id,
          token: jwt.sign({ userId: user_id }, "TOOOKEN", {
            expiresIn: "24h",
          }),
        });
      } else {
        console.log("not match");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ err: "une erreur" });
    }
  });
};
```

The frontend :

```
 const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await POST(ENDPOINTS.USER_LOGIN, userLogin);
    // await GET(ENDPOINTS.USER_LOGIN)
    fetch("http://localhost:4200/api/auth/login")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  };
```

This login fonction send data to my backend, then the backend checks if an user exist in database with the first POST request. If yes, the backend send in json format some data that i wan't to put in the local storage of the user, so after the POST request, i do another request with GET method to retrieve the json data sent from the back, but i have an 404 error.

How can i get my data sent by the back ?

Comment: You're not sending any param with your GET request. How should the backend know which user you're trying to retrieve? Also you're backend function is expecting to find user's credentials in `req.body`, but there's no body in a get request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with the SQL statement, underneath the if statement you have can you print the error like so:

```
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

and tell me the result please